# Springboot 2.7.6 fails to automatically assemble RedisTemplate using redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I encountered a strange problem today,When I use RestTemplate and RedisTemplate, RestTemplate is managed by the Spring framework, but RedisTemplate is not managed. They are both in one class file.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Serializable> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory){
        RedisTemplate<String,Serializable> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        //配置序列化器 以下均是
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.java());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

This is my dependency：

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This is an error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field redisTemplate in com.school.repair.common.HttpRequestUtils required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Guys, give me some advice

Answer (score 1):

Share your pom.xml and application.properties/yml file, need more info.

None the less, I think you should configure a custom jedis connection factory in your code. There might be some issue with your lettusConnectionFactory.

add following in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

And add a jedis Connection factory in your config file like following

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Serializable> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Serializable> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.json());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(RedisSerializer.string());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(RedisSerializer.java());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```